# android show internal html file

Tags: android, webview

i have followed the instructions to show a web view in my app, is working fine,

but now i need to show an internal html file,

so my first question,

is ok just to drag and drop my html folder in the "res" folder of my app in eclipse?

if is so,
how can I refer to the location:

> res\html\index.html

so I can show the index.html in my app?

what to change in my Url, to work with the URI??

> mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

is this path the only thing to change?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the index.html file in the `assets` folder. Then, create a `layout` with a `WebView` in it and set it as the layout like this in your `Activity`

```
setContentView(R.layout.html_layout); //load the layout XML file
WebView mbrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mwebview); //get the WebView from the layout XML
mbrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); //set the HTML
```

html_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mwebview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```